# Resolving files in junit

Tags: java, junit, jenkins

I'm reading files in java using the following line in junit,

getClassLoader().getResource(Some_Value);

The same works fine in eclipse, but gives problems when it runs in jenkins, since the jenkins executes the instrumented junit so the class loader points to different class path. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Use relative classpaths to reference your files. Also you could leverage the 'Class-Path' attribute from your jar's Manifest file and add dependencies there. There's build tools that can do that automatically. Not sure if jenkins will pick that manifest entries, but I assume it would!

Answer (score 0):

from classpath resource:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/Your_file_Path")
```

from ClassLoader, all paths are "absolute" already - there's no context, from which they could be relative. Therefore you don't need a leading slash.

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                            .getResourceAsStream("Your_file_Path");
```

from Class, the path is relative to the package of the class unless, you include a leading slash, so if you don't want to use the current package, include a slash like this:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Your_file_Path");
```